# How to add click event on each ContexMenu item using list?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I'm trying to convert a string list to `ContexMenu`. How do I apply click events to each item and display a message with the text of the clicked item?

CS

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
            "item1", "item2", "item3"
        };
        context.ItemsSource = list;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="wpftest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpftest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Name="grid" Background="Gray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="context"/>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways.

Through building `ContextMenu` from code-behind:

```
// ----- XAML part
<Grid Name="grid" Background="Gray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>

// ----- Code part 

// Initialize context menu
var contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
      
// Fill context menu with items  
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    // Create simple item with some text on it
    var menuItem = new MenuItem { Header = "Item #" + i };
    // Add click handler
    menuItem.Click += delegate { _ = MessageBox.Show(menuItem.Header + " was clicked"); };
    // Add item to menu
    contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
}

// Set context menu to grid
grid.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
```

Through setting click handlers from XAML for each `MenuItem`:

```
// ----- XAML part
<Grid Name="grid" Background="Gray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Item #1" Click="ContextMenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Item #2" Click="ContextMenuItem_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Item #3" Click="ContextMenuItem_Click"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>

// ----- Code part

// One click handler for each MenuItem.
// You can differ MenuItems by Header property for example
private void ContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is MenuItem menuItem)
        _ = MessageBox.Show(menuItem.Header + " was clicked");
}
```